# How to pass props down with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype, styled-components

I just started recently to work with styled components and I'm wondering how I could adapt this kind of code to be compliant with them. What I would like to do is having a default behaviour in my component `AppText.js` but that I could overwrite with components props. I might have to change my way of seeing things but I'm quite sure there is a clean solution to this with this library. This is what it looks like in my actual code.

**AppText.js**

```
type Props = {
  children?: React.Node,
  onPress?: Function,
  style?: StyleSheet.Styles,
  textStyle?: StyleSheet.Styles,
}

const AppText = ({ children, onPress, style, textStyle }: Props) => {
  if (!children) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ ...styles.appTextView, ...style }}>
      <Text onPress={onPress} style={{ ...styles.textLabel, ...textStyle }}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

AppText.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
  onPress: () => {},
  style: {},
  textStyle: {},
}
```

**Usage**

```
<AppText
  onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
  style={styles.cancel}
  textStyle={styles.cancelText}
>
  Retour
</AppText>
```

Comment: I didn't link my whole component but I have some styles defined above for my AppText that can be overwritten via passing props to the component. It could work for a callback function too like a handler if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer by myself, it was quite easy in the end.
For reference, here is my code.

**App.js**

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

import MyText from '@components/MyText'

const App = () => (
  <Container>
    <Welcome>Welcome to React Native!</Welcome>
    <Instructions>To get started, edit App.js</Instructions>
    <Instructions>{instructions}</Instructions>
    <MyStyledText
      onPress={() => {
        alert('You clicked this text!')
      }}
    >
      Press here
    </MyStyledText>
  </Container>
)

// Styles
const MyStyledText = styled(MyText)`
  background-color: red
`

export { App as default }
```

**MyText.js**

```
/* @flow */
import type { Node } from 'react'
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

// Styles
const StyledText = styled.Text`
  background-color: ${({ style }) => style.backgroundColor || 'blue'};
  font-size: ${({ style }) => style.fontSize || 50};
`

type MyTextProps = {
  children: Node,
  onPress?: Function,
  style?: Object,
}

// My component renders with a background-color of red and a font-size of 50!
const MyText = ({ children, onPress, style }: MyTextProps) => (
  <StyledText onPress={onPress} style={style}>
    {children}
  </StyledText>
)

MyText.defaultProps = {
  onPress: () => {},
  style: {},
}

export { MyText as default }
```

Comment: Now I'm trying to resolve the following: Cannot call `styled.Text` because property `style` is missing in  object type [1] in the first argument of array element.Flow(InferError). styled-components_v4.x.x.js(256, 66): [1] object type